# Install XCode 4.5 beta along XCode 4.3 to keep App Store publishing option

Tags: xcode, setup

What is the correct way to install `Xcode 4.5` beta along existing `Xcode 4.3` stable?

I want to keep App Store publishing option.

Last time i did install an Xcode beta, it wiped out my existing install and I wasn't able to push to the App Store anymore.

I guess with the new Xcode "AppStore sandboxed" packaging, there must be new ways to achieve that in a clean way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually if you read the release notes, the file is already the app bundle. So there is no need to install. Just drag the budge to your Application folder and that is it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this messes with any NDAs. So...

Download. Install. Run. Right-click and keep it in Dock. Drag it to beside your standard Xcode icon and appreciate that this has PREVIEW written on it. Apple seems to have made this one elegant and easy, compared with the past.

Comment: By "install", I simply mean "drat to Applications folder", BTW...